# Network protocol internals

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, lan

Is there any good book about networks and network protocols?  One question I currently have is: How does the operating system determine the IP address of the router in a LAN?

I want to understand those basics. I know that I can look up most of the common protocols by searching for their respective RFC, but I don't even know which protocols are used for which purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system knows the ip address of the first router ([default gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway)), because someone told it - either manually when configuring the TCP/IP settings or dynamically via [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), [BOOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_Protocol) or similar.

There are plenty of good book suggestions in the closed question "[What are good books on computer networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211521/what-are-good-books-on-computer-networks)"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/kurose-ross/

http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Computer_Networks.html?id=Pd-z64SJRBAC

Both are good books. Enjoy !!